# Assiging parameters to sqldatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource, formview

I'm trying to get data from SQL Server and use it in a formview, but the formview control won't get any data from the datasource.

(The datasource gets parameter on page load)

Output is just: "There is nothing to see here" and an empty table.

Here is the datasource and formview tags:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:igroup20_test2ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [member] where ([id] = @idd)">
   <SelectParameters>
       <asp:Parameter Name="idd" Type="String" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="id">
   <EmptyDataTemplate>
   There is nothing to see here.
   </EmptyDataTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
               <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("f_name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@idd", "077763554");
        FormView1.DataBind();
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

You have two problems:

1. first you don't need to **add** the parameter again - it's already defined in your markup
2. you don't have to use a `@` in your parameter name - just the name will do.

So use this code instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["idd"].DefaultValue = "077763554";
    FormView1.DataBind();
}
```

That should do the trick - set the `.DefaultValue` on the existing parameter, and use the `idd` parameter name, as defined in your markup (`<asp:Parameter Name="idd" Type="String" />`)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are adding 2 parameters here. One declarative and one in your code behind.

Try to add only the parameter in your code behind. also change the name to `idd` instead of `@idd`.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:igroup20_test2ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [member] where ([id] = @idd)">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("idd", "077763554");
        FormView1.DataBind();
 }
```