# SqlDataSource - SelectCommand with session variable filter

Tags: asp.net, session, sqldatasource, selectcommand

ASP.NET 2.0 framework

I'm trying to list all user related entries when the user visits the page. I have a session variable set with the visitor in session. Now I want to query the database with that ID. It seems to be executing, but no results are being returned (I'm displaying the contents in a seperate code section).

Please help!

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
ID="UserReports" 
runat="server"
ConnectionString= "<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand = "SELECT [ID], [ReportName], [ReportPath] FROM [Pan].          
[dbo].[Reports] WHERE ([VisitorID] = @VisitorID)"
OnSelecting  = "SqldsExample_Selecting">

<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="VisitorID" Type="String"/>
</SelectParameters>    
</asp:SqlDataSource>

On the code behind:

Sub SqldsExample_Selecting(sender As Object, e As      
SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs)

UserReports.SelectParameters.Add("@VisitorID", Session("VisitorID"))

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm looking for VB, not C# please.

Comment: You can take a look at marc_s' answer in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000390/assiging-parameters-to-sqldatasource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `<asp:Parameter>`.You should be using `<asp:SessionParameter>` to access the session variable directly:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="VisitorID" SessionField="VisitorID" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis. With your suggestion, I'm getting the following:

Compiler Error Message: BC31143: Method 'Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selected(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub SqlDataSourceSelectingEventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs)'.

Comment: Remove the Selecting event handler completely.Set the session in the page load or on the previous page and access it using the example I provided.Have a look at this example - http://forums.asp.net/t/1062765.aspx?sqldatasource+using+session+data+in+select+parameters.Do it exactly the way ecbruck suggests

Comment: Thanks Dennis.

Removed the Selecting event handler completely. And the session is being set on the pageLoad.

Session("VisitorID") = userID

Now getting:

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
Source Error: 

     Line 15: <asp:SqlDataSource
     Line 16: ID="UserReports" 
     Line 17: runat="server"

Comment: That means one of the controls in your .aspx page is not well formed(doesn't have a closing tag,has an invalid character e.t.c) inspect your .aspx page and find the problem.And remember to mark my post as answered if it helped you

Comment: Thank you Denis. I was able to get the parse error corrected and now able to see the results with the following:

    <asp:Repeater
    id="Repeater1"
    DataSourceId="SQLsourceUserReports"
    Runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

    <asp:HyperLink
    id="HyperLink1"
    Text='<%# Eval("ReportName") %>'
    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ReportPath", "{0}") %>'
    runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>  


The reason I had Selecting event handler was because I wanted to track the user clicks on the links above. Can you please help?

Comment: Thank you for your directions Denis -I managed to get the most. I'm currently having an issue when users click on those links (using LinkButtons), if the URL is a web page, all goes well. But when the URL underneth the LinkButton is URL that's directly linked to an .xlsx, I get the "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed."...any thoughts? I expect to have a 'Save As' window to appear when such links are clicked...Please advise.

Comment: I'm using 
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="MyLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton_Click"  PostBackUrl = '<%# Bind("UserItems", "{0}") %>'  Text='<%# Bind("ItemNames") %>'  ></asp:LinkButton>

Comment: Please mark as answered if my answer helped you and ask a new question on stackoverflow rearding your other problem and someone will help you